# React API call with bearer token

Tags: reactjs, api, token

I'm new to code and react. I am trying to make an API call to get the data. The problem is that the bearer token given to me expires every 24hrs and I don't know how to insert the Token code as a variable to my header authorization in my request in react to make it renew when it needs and deliver to me the JSON information.

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and it won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to come here and SHOUT at us when you're asking for free help. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Do you have example code you could provide for us of your requests?

Answer (score 2):

something like this might work

```
import React from 'react';
const App = () => {
  const token = "yourtokenhere";
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('https://example.test/', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`}
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(json => setResult(json));
  },[]);

  return (
    <>
      {JSON.stringify(result)}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For the authorization header, I would suggest `interceptor`.

**Interceptors** can perform tasks such as *URL manipulation, logging, adding tokens to the header, etc* **before** and **after** making an API request and response.

for **fetch()** API use, `npm install fetch-intercept --save`

```js
import fetchIntercept from 'fetch-intercept';
 
const registerIntercept = fetchIntercept.register({
    request: function (url, config) {
        // Modify the url or config here
        const authHeader = new Headers(config.headers);
        authHeader.append('Authorization', 'Bearer 232Qefsg4fg4g'); // your token
        config.headers = authHeader;
        return [url, config];
    },
 
    requestError: function (error) {
        // Called when an error occured during another 'request' interceptor call
        return Promise.reject(error);
    },
 
    response: function (response) {
        // Modify or log the reponse object
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    },
 
    responseError: function (error) {
        // Handle a fetch error
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
});
```

for **Axios** use, `npm install axios`

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
  // `req` is the Axios request config, so you can modify
  // the `headers`.
  req.headers.authorization = 'my secret token';
  return req;
});
```